# Why is the voltage regulator's output current not what I'm expecting?

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-measurement

I've recently bought a couple of Sanyo LA5003 voltage regulators ([datasheet](http://www.tvsat.com.pl/pdf/L/la5002_san.pdf)). From the datasheet, I understood that the highest possible current on the output can be 60mA. However, when I connect it to several (2 or 4) series-connected 1.5V AA batteries, I get, respectively, around 120mA and around 140mA.

Here's how I'm testing the current:
[image]
(pin 1 is on the right)

What am I doing wrong and/or misunderstanding?

PS. I've tried measuring on more than one of them, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are measuring the current incorrectly, and you are misunderstanding what the term "maximum current" means.

1. You are measuring current like you would measure voltage. In order to measure current, you need to place your meter in series with your load. If you place it in parallel, then the meter will short-circuit your source (regulator in this example) and give you a (usually) nonsensical answer.
2. The datasheet specifies maximum values, such as maximum current and maximum power dissipation, and it is *your* job to make sure that *you* don't exceed those parameters. The maximum current is the most current that you can safely use without damaging the circuit, but this part won't stop you from exceeding the maximum current.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All three were eligible to be accepted, but yours won the random number lottery :).

Answer (score 4):

The 60 mA is under Absolute Maximum Ratings, which means you **never** should exceed that at the expense of damage to the regulator. Since you can get twice that out of it it appears that there is no internal current limiter. Which is BAD, every regulator nowadays has current limiting.

It appears that you'll have to make sure yourself that the 60 mA is never exceeded. The datasheet's electrical characteristics and the graphs are specified at 20 mA.

There are lots of regulators with better specs available, like uA ground current instead of mA. Also the look of the datasheet doesn't give me much confidence.

**edit**
Possible alternative: [Seiko S-812C30B](http://datasheet.sii-ic.com/en/voltage_regulator/S812C_E.pdf):

- output voltage 2.0 V to 6.0 V, selectable in 100 mV steps
- 2% output voltage accuracy
- up to 16 V in
- **low ground current of 1 µA typical, 1.8 µA maximum** (that's 1/1000th of the LA5003!)
- LDO
- short-circuit protected
- power-down mode
- guaranteed stable without output capacitor

I'm a fan. In the past I didn't recommend it, though, because of it's bad availability, unless you needed 100k/year. But now I see you can get them at Digikey too.

Comment: So, a stupid question, but just to make sure - if I get a voltage regulator with current limiting, let's say say of 60 mA, I won't get anything more than than that, even using the way I'm measuring currently?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato - Yes, that's what current limiting means. Now what you did was very naughty :-), and extreme: if you short-circuit the output you have zero voltage. If in a normal circuit the regulator will overload the output voltage will also decrease. Say you have a 50 ohm load on the 3 V regulator, then you're at the 60 mA limit. Lower the load to 40 ohm and the current limiting will set in, so that instead of 75 mA you still have only 60, and 60 mA x 40 ohm is 2.4 V. The regulator decreases output voltage to protect itself. Some regulators may shut down completely.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Because all the answers were good, I decided to use a random number generator to pick the accepted one. Unfortunately, your wasn't picked. But of course, I've upvoted it.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato - There was a time when they did this with dice. The times are definitely changing :-)

Comment: Well, it was definitely easier to grab some random bits from Hotbits than to lift my **se from the chair and find a die... which pretty much reinforces your observation ;).

Answer (score 2):

The great advantage of this part compared to regulators like the LM317 or LM7405/ LM340 is the very low dropout voltage of typically 0.2 V. This compares to about 2V for an LM317 of LM7805. This means that Vin-Vout can be as low as about 0.2V.

In your application the LA5003 is rated at 3V out nominal so you need at least 3.2V in and really more like 3.5V to be safe. So 2 x AA cells is not enough voltage and 4 ells is more than you need except when the battery is very very flat. For most purposes 3 x AA cells would bge OK.

> What am I doing wrong and/or misunderstanding?

I assume from your diagram and text that you are measuring short circuit current.
 If so, that is not what the data sheet specifies.
 The current is specified with the device working properly - ie with not less than about 50 ohms load. With a short circuit 'all bets are off".

The Ioutmax rating is the absolute maximum you should ever take - NOT what it may give. Interestingly, the Iout versus Vout graph on page 3/4 , 3rd down in left hand column, shows test current up to 100 mA.
 Vout was 3.12 V at no load, falling to 3.10V at 100 mA.
 They are not great respecters of their own 60 mA absolute maximum rating :-).

The quiesecent current is not nice but as long as you are happy with the max mA rating the device is quite nice in a number of respects.

Comment: I see. One question - where is the 50 Ohm estimate derived from?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato - The part is specified to provide a certain current max so should initially bes tested at about that current. After that yiu can load it up  to see if it mainstains output voltage at gigher load but just shorting it is 'cheating". So at say 100 mA and 5V, r = V/I = 5/ 0.1A = 50 Ohms.

Comment: Ohm's law, of course *slaps own forehead*. But since this is a 3V/60mA regulator, you actually meant 3/0.06, right? Regardless, your answer was great, but since the other were also equally eligible to be accepted, I resorted to a random pick. Unfortunately, yours wasn't, but of course I still upvoted it.